# Derivative Help: $f(x) = x^3\,e^{5x-7}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to find the derivative of the following function:
$${\rm f}\left(\,x\,\right)= x^{3}{\rm e}^{5x - 7}$$
but I don't know where to start with this problem. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Perhaps using the product rule?  You will need the chain rule as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the product rule and the chain rule.

Call $g(x) = x^3$ and $h(x) = e^{5x-7}$, or is it $h(x) = e^{5x}-7$?

By the product rule: $$f' = g'(x)h(x) + g(x) h'(x)$$

To find $h'(x)$, you'll need to use the chain-rule.

Comment: would h'(x)=5e^5x-7?

Comment: Yes, if $h(x) = e^{5x-7},$ then $\, h'(x) = 5e^{5x-7}.\,$ But if $h(x) = e^{5x}-7,\,$ then $\,h'(x)= 5e^{5x}$.

Comment: I have this so far,(3x^2)(e^5x-7)+(x^3)(5e^5x-7). Now what I do?

Comment: That's correct. If you want, you can simplify by noting that $x^2e^{5x-7}$ is a common factor in each term. So $$f'(x) = x^2e^{5x-7}\big(3 +5 x\big)$$

Comment: Would that be the final answer then?

Comment: Yes, but note that your answer is correct as well. The two forms are equivalent. The only difference is that what I wrote is simply your answer, factored.

Comment: Okay thank you so much, you are a life saver!!!

Answer (score 0):

if it is $f(x)=x^3(e^{5x}-7)$ then we get by the product and chaine rule
$f'(x)=3x^2(e^{5x}-7)+x^3(e^{5x}5)$
simplifying this in any minutes.
It is simplified to
$f'(x)=x^2 \left(e^{5 x} (5 x+3)-21\right)$

Comment: Your exact TeX for the simplified form is produced by `Simplify[D[x^3 (Exp[5 x] - 7), x]] // TeXForm` in Mathematica - hence the downvote.